# Custom lightning component broke the formatting (overide CSS)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system, aura, slds

So I created a custom self-registration lightning component based off a standard component by using:

```
 implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
```

Once I did that, my formatting for the custom component broke despite only adding one line of code to the component.  The style class for some reason changes from "branded" to "neutral"  and "uiButton--none" to "uiButton--default"

```
<!--PROPER STANDARD BUTTON-->
<button 
class="slds-button slds-button--brand uiButton--none uiButton" 
aria-live="off" 
type="button" 
data-aura-class="uiButton--none uiButton"/>

<!--BROKEN BUTTON-->
<button 
class="slds-button slds-button--neutral sfdc_button uiButton--default uiButton"
 aria-live="off" 
type="button" 
data-aura-class="uiButton--default uiButton/"
```

**Any ideas how I can override the CSS, where is the "uiButton--default" and "neutral " coming from?**

[image: custom vs standard]

Comment: have you tried re-styling it in the custom component style sheet?

Comment: I’m not sure how to use Style Classes in the CSS

Comment: the HTML for your "broken"  button shouldnt work, im guessing you did a typo, but as is it shouldnt even render.

Comment: any reason why you are not using a lighting:button in your component? (or have you tried using one and get the same behavior?)

Comment: I was attempting to make it more readable.  Something could have not translated properly.  I edited in the browser console and was able to make the proper change by editing the html

Comment: I’m using whatever was in the standard component which was a <ui:button> tag.

Comment: I’ll post the lightning code and css in about an hour

Comment: @glls YUSS!  Changing it to a Lightning:Button worked.  Seems that the deprecated controls are acting funny.  That component is riddled with errors such as "helpler" and "helper"  Feel free to add that as a solution and I'll mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my earlier comment, the markup you provided for the "Broken" Button seems incomplete, however, I suggest you use a [lightning:button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_button.htm) component which has the advantage of having SLDS embeded within it when it is rendered.